# Postgresql@12 on Big Sur Won't Start

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, macos-big-sur

Installed `postgresql@12` and for some reason won't start:

```
/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@12 stable ❯ pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@12/bin/postgres start
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@12/bin/postgres/postmaster.pid": Not a directory

/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@12 stable ❯ brew services list
Name          Status  User Plist
postgresql@12 error   rich /Users/rich/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@12.plist

~ ❯ sudo su - postgres
su: unknown login: postgres   

~ ❯ brew services start postgresql@12
Service `postgresql@12` already started, use `brew services restart postgresql@12` to restart.
~ ❯ brew services restart postgresql@12
Stopping `postgresql@12`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql@12` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@12)
==> Successfully started `postgresql@12` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@12)
~ ❯ sudo su - postgres
su: unknown login: postgres
```

Not sure why there isn't a `postgres` user created with the install.

Anybody know what I can do to get this back in line?  Cheers

Comment: Sometimes just running brew to uninstall postgresql and resinstall it clears up various postgres startup issues.  So you might try that unless better answers get posted.

Comment: @DCSlagel Did that several times.  Turns out many others are finding the same issues.  The `postgres` application seems to be working.

Comment: Are you able to connect to psql using `psql -U <your-user_login> -h localhost`?

Comment: This looks to be the same or related issue.  They solve it by (re-)creating the postgres user: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131454/add-a-user-for-postgres-on-mac

Comment: Can't test it now.  I used the `postgres.app` and have it running under that installation.  But the fact that it couldn't make the `postgres` user, is not right.  Someone said somewhere in November that Apple was contacted about this.

Comment: I can __now__ log in using psql as per your comment.